# centos7 not installing mysql

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, yum

I've installed centos7 recently, but, when I am trying to install Mysql using the command:

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

I keep getting Exiting on user cancel while I am not hitting any keyboard button.. here is the output:

```
install  2 Packages (+9 Dependent packages)
 Total size: 80 M Total download size: 79 M Is this ok [y/d/N]: y 
    Downloading packages: 
    No Presto metadata available for base No Presto metadata available for mysql56-community mysql-community-client-5.6.24-3.el7.x86_64.rpm |7.6 MB     00:32 ...  mysql-community-server-5.6.24-3.el7.x86_64.rpm        |  46MB     00:41 ...  mysql-community-libs-5.6.24-3.el7.x86_64.rpm      |    0 B     00:30 ...  (1/9): mysql-community-cli 0% [                ] 4.7 kB/s | 159 kB  283:33 ETA 

    Exiting on user cancel
```

what is the problem? why I can not install it? what is the soloution?

thanks for helping.
note: my yum have the following plugins: fastmirror, axelget, langpacks.

Comment: try enabling presto plugin.

Comment: how to enable it? sorry for this beginners question but I am really new to centos and redhat based operation sysytems

Answer (score 1):

Try these two preliminary steps and then go for `yum install mysql-community-server`

1. Firstly clean your metadata: This cleans up any xml metadata that may have been cached from any enabled repository

   `$ sudo yum clean metadata`
2. Then upgrade all of your CentOS system software to the latest version

   `$ sudo yum update`